# In IOS, How to Connect Nearest Bluetooth devices Based on RSSI

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-bluetooth

In didDiscoverPeripheral method, I have Peripheral,RSSI of scanned devices. But i need to select Nearest Bluetooth device based on RSSI Value. I am able get Nearest RSSI value, But i am unable to mapping RSSI with Peripheral.Can anybody help me on this.

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager )central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI { 
    ScannedPeripheral sensor = [ScannedPeripheral initWithPeripheral:peripheral rssi:RSSI.intValue isPeripheralConnected:NO];
    sensor.RSSI = [RSSI intValue]; 
    [self.Arr addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",sensor.RSSI]];
    NSArray *qwe = [self.Arr sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2){ return [obj1 compare:obj2];}];
}
```

Comment: Please include your current code in your question. `didDiscover peripheral` only returns a single `CBPeripheral` object, so you cannot find the device with the highest RSSI in a single function call.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the code _there_, not in a comment. After you paste it you can select it and press Ctrl+K or click the `{}` button to format it as code.

Comment: code included in question from comments, tags corrected